# Ruby tests don't run

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm trying Ruby and Unit Testing but my simple attempts at running test cases are returning nothing. The curious thing is that the tests were running before and returning the number of tests that were ran and the number of assertions and so on. But for some reason they stopped running. I have two separated files:

```
#TipoMovimento.rb

class TipoMovimento
    attr_accessor :designacao
    attr_accessor :cor
    attr_accessor :regras

    def initialize(aDesignacao, aCor, asRegras)
        @designacao = aDesignacao
        @cor = aCor
        @regras = asRegras
    end

    def ==(other)
        other.class == self.class && other.state == self.state
    end

    def state
        self.instance_variables.map { |variable| self.instance_variable_get variable }
    end
end
```

and

```
#TesteTipoMovimento.rb

require './TipoMovimento.rb'
require 'test/unit'

class TesteTipoMovimento < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def setup
        @tm = TipoMovimento.new('Des1', 'Cor1', ['r1', 'r2'])
    end

    def tc_equal
        tm2 = TipoMovimento.new('Des1', 'Cor1', ['r1', 'r2'])
        assert_true(tm2 == @tm)
        tm2 = TipoMovimento.new('Des2', 'Cor1', ['r1', 'r2'])
        assert_false(tm2 == @tm)
    end
end
```

Both files are in the same folder. Unfortunately, when I run the test file, nothing happens. After I press enter the prompt simply ignores my command. Something like:

```
C:\My Ruby Files\>ruby TesteTipoMovimento.rb

C:\My Ruby Files\>
```

This is obviously something simple that I'm missing, so if anyone could help me I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no tests in that test class. To make method a test, prefix its name with `test_`.

```
class TesteTipoMovimento < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def setup
        @tm = TipoMovimento.new('Des1', 'Cor1', ['r1', 'r2'])
    end

    def test_tc_equal
        tm2 = TipoMovimento.new('Des1', 'Cor1', ['r1', 'r2'])
        assert_true(tm2 == @tm)
        tm2 = TipoMovimento.new('Des2', 'Cor1', ['r1', 'r2'])
        assert_false(tm2 == @tm)
    end
end
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I had read somewhere that the recommendation was to prefix the test cases with tc_ and now that you mentioned it, it was when the tests stopped working.